# Probability of an odd amount of sixes when rolling a 6-sided die 10 times.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

**Rolling a fair die 10 times, what is the probability it will give an odd amount of sixes?**

---

So the outcomes I'm interested in are:

1 six in 10 rolls

or

3 sixes in 10 rolls

or

5 sixes in 10 rolls

or

7 sixes in 10 rolls

or

9 sixes in 10 rolls

---

Can the probability of getting 1 six in 10 rolls be described as $ 1 - ({5 \over 6})^9$  ?

And if the above is correct, I should be able to continue with

the probability of getting 3 sixes in 10 rolls as $ 1 - ({5 \over 6})^7$

the probability of getting 5 sixes in 10 rolls as $ 1 - ({5 \over 6})^5$

the probability of getting 7 sixes in 10 rolls as $ 1 - ({5 \over 6})^3$

the probability of getting 9 sixes in 10 rolls as $ 1 - ({5 \over 6})^1$

All I need to do now is to add them together, correct?

$$
P (\text{odd  amount  of  sixes  in  10  rolls}) = (1 - {5 \over 6}^9) + (1 - {5 \over 6}^7) + (1 - {5 \over 6}^5) + (1 - {5 \over 6}^3) + (1 - {5 \over 6}^1)
$$

Help is appreciated,

Comment: See about [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: Yes! Binomial distribution is the way to go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your start is correct but not the calculations,

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

The formula is $\boxed{\color{red}{\text{Pr}(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}}}$ for $k$ successe in $n$ trials

$k=1:\quad$For  $1$ six in $10$ rolls $X\sim B(10,\frac 1 6),\quad\text{Pr}(X=1)=\binom{10}{1}(1/6)^1(1-1/6)^{10-1}$

$k=3:\quad$For  $3$ six in $10$ rolls $Y\sim B(10,\frac 1 6),\quad\text{Pr}(Y=3)=\binom{10}{3}(1/6)^3(1-1/6)^{10-3}$

Do the same for $k=5,7,9$. The answer is the sum of the probabilitys.

Comment: But why is the binomial coefficient relevant? Lets say that I want to get a six on the very first flip, that's $(1/6)$ and then for the remaining 9 flips I don't want a six. Then it makes sense to me to multiply $(1/6)$ with $(5/6)^9$. It's not completely clear to me why I would multiply it with the binomial coefficient

Comment: @user3067688 This is the formula of [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of possibilities for $k$ success in $n$ trials

Answer (score 1):

No no no!

Probability for exactly $n \space (\in \{0,1,\dots 10\})$ amount of sixes in ten rolls is

$${10\choose n}  \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^n \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{10-n}$$

Now sum these for odd numbers and you have your solution.

Comment: I somehow thought the first was correct but it's not: $1-(5/6)^9 \neq {6 \choose 1}(1/6)^1(5/6)^9$.

Comment: The meaning of the probability $1−(5/6)^{10}$ is that there is at least $1$ six. Notice there must be $10$ in the exponent in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursion for solving this problem:

Let $A_n$ be the event of having an odd number of sixes after $n$ rolls.

We have that $P(A_n)=\frac56 P(A_{n-1})+\frac16(1-P(A_{n-1}))=\frac23 P(A_{n-1})+\frac16$.

You should be able to use this to solve your problem, either by working out the values to $P(A_{10})$ explicitly, or by solving the recursion (i.e., getting a nonrecursive formula for $P(A_n)$).

Edit: The initial condition is $P(A_0)=0$.